# jmeter login test splunk on RHEL 8

Tags: jmeter, splunk

I am new to jmeter and need to do a login test for my splunk vm on rhel 8 using my windows server 2022 to run jmeter, but I got unauthorized or bad request errors.

I tried to record and use all the variables involved, but could not understand the value cval.

[image]

if I exclude those fields and only use username and password, I get unauthorized error, even when I have added a HTTP Authorization Manager

Any help to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [**correlate**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) this `cval` parameter value

1. First open your Login page using HTTP GET request. It will return the login page and in the response source there will be this `cval` dynamic value:

   [image]

   add a Post-Processor, for example [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) and configure it to fetch this `cval` value from the response:

   [image]
2. Once done replace (recorded?) hard-coded value of `cval` with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the extracted value:

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and you should be good to go:

   [image]